# Filter array to one row per multiple of ten, based on difference?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have an array which holds the values from a resultset. The outline of my code to retrieve the array is:

```java
public String[][] ref_Details() {
  int i = 0;
  String a[][] = new String[47][11];
  try
  {  
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql=" select b.LOGTIME, b.beam_current, b.beam_energy ..."; // shortened
    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while(rs.next()) {
      for(int j=0; j<11; j++)
        a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);

      i++;
    }
  }
  catch( Exception e ) { ... }
  finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }
  return a;
}
```

The sample table obtained is:

[image]

From the table it is clear that the second column `beam_current` has values which are near to each integer multiple of ten from 0 to 220: (0, 10, 20 ... 220). I want to filter my data set so that, for each multiple of ten, I only select the row closest to that multiple. For this I:

1. subtract 10 from all the rows of `beam_current` and find the differences obtained: the row with the smallest difference is the only row in which I'm interested for that multiple of 10. T
2. repeat step 1 until a total of 220 is subtracted from all rows.

My expected result is 22 rows instead of the original 47 from the sample data. For example, the row numbered 21 in the sample data picture above would correspond to the selected row for the value `130`.

My problem is that I'm not seeing my expected results. The code I tried is:

```java
public int[] ref_BeamCurrent() {
  int i = 0;
  int[] arr = new int[47];
  try
  {  
    con = getConnection();
    ...
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while(rs.next()) 
    { 
      for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
      {
        arr[i] = rs.getInt(2);
        System.out.println(arr);
        while (i < arr.length && number <= 210)
        {
          arr[i] = arr[i] - number;
          System.out.println(arr);
          number = number + 10;
          System.out.println(number);
          i = i + 1;
          // System.out.println(arr);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch( Exception e ) { ... }
  finally { ... }
  return arr;
}
```

This code seems to be selecting entirely the wrong rows - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why couldn't you get the sum of 10 to 220 and deduct it form the second column.  you could get the min value while deducting the above value as you are looping through

Comment: @SRY_JAVA I have edited your question to try and clarify your goal and the issue you are having. Is it still accurately describing what you expect to see and the problem you have?

Comment: @AndyBrown,yes its exactly showing my goal,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should think about this in a different way. What you want to do is find the distance from a multiple of ten for each row.

- The closest multiple of ten is given by the expression `double mult = 10d * Math.round(v / 10d)`
- The distance from the multiple of ten is given by the expression `double delta = Math.abs(v - mult)`
- For any value of `mult`, the row you want is the one with the smallest `delta` value.

Therefore you only have to iterate the rows once.

1. Get the `beam_value` for a row and find it's `mult` and `delta`.
2. If the row's `delta` is closer than any previously found `delta` for `mult`, then log that row for that `mult`, otherwise ignore it.
3. repeat until there are no more rows.

Also note that this approach will prevent a single row being logged against more than one multiple of ten, which is hard to prevent with other approaches.

By example (and I have faked the data as I don't have your SQL query). The input data:

```
`0.5, 12.10, 13.00, 16.01, 21.52`
```

gives the output below, which is correct (index 1 is closer to `10` than index 2, and index 4 is closer to `20` than index 3):

```
   10x  row value
     0    0 0.5000
    10    1 12.1000
    20    4 21.5200
```

with the code:

```
public static void findClosestRowsToMultiplesOfTen() {
    // fake row values
    double[] vals = new double[]{ 0.5, 12.10, 13.00, 16.01, 21.52 };

    //  get the max value, and its multiple of ten to get the number of buckets
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (double v : vals) max = Math.max(max, v);
    int bucketCount = 1 + (int)(max/10);

    //  initialise the buckets array to store the closest values
    double[][] buckets = new double[bucketCount][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++){
        // store the current smallest delta in the first element
        buckets[i][0] = Double.MAX_VALUE; 
        // store the current "closest" index in the second element
        buckets[i][1] = -1d;
        // store the current "closest" value in the third element
        buckets[i][2] = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    //  iterate the rows
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
    {
        //  get the value from the row
        double v = vals[i];
        //  get the closest multiple of ten to v
        double mult = getMultipleOfTen(v);
        //  get the absolute distance of v from the multiple of ten
        double delta = Math.abs(mult - v);
        //  get the bucket index based on the value of `mult`
        int bIdx = (int)(mult / 10d);
        //    test the last known "smallest delta" for this bucket
        if (buckets[bIdx][0] > delta)
        {
            //  this is closer than the last known "smallest delta"
            buckets[bIdx][0] = delta;
            buckets[bIdx][1] = i;
            buckets[bIdx][2] = v;
        }
    }

    //   print out the result
    System.out.format("    10x row value%n");
    for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++)
    {
        double[] bucket = buckets[i];
        int multipleOfTen = i * 10;
        double rowIndex = bucket[1];
        double rowValue = bucket[2];
        System.out.format("    %,2d %,4.0f %.4f%n", 
          multipleOfTen, rowIndex, rowValue);
    }
}
public static double getMultipleOfTen(double v)
{
    return 10d * Math.round(v / 10d);
}
```

Comment: when **I replace your vals value with my original data** by using sql query and rs.getInt(2).When I print the values then its rounding off the values of the second column to match with values10,20 ...till 220 but **I don't want to round off the values but want to print the actual values of beam_current i.e second column**

Comment: As in your vals value,when you print the values 12.100,21.52 is being printed ,**but if my value is 20.02 ,it is being round off to 20** and when its 30.01 it is being rounded off to 30 .**I just want to print the actual values of second column** and nothing else.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA [`rs.getInt(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)) will truncate the column value you are reading from the sql query (e.g. 20.02 will be read as 20). You need [`rs.getDouble(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble(int)) or [`rs.getFloat(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble(int)).

Comment: ,you are correct.How can I show this retrieved column with my display table at place of actual second column.i.e. now I have to replace the beam_current of the table retrieved from sql query with the new beam_currents which I retrieve.I'm using JSP as view technology

Comment: @SRY_JAVA I'm not sure I understand your question. Comments aren't designed for long discussions so it is probably worth you asking a new question to get an answer for this follow-on question.

Comment: How to place these new values which I got i.e values which are near to multiples of 10 with the actual values which I retrieved from the sql query .I want to display the table will the new calculated values of second column.

Comment: ,I can't understand **for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++)**loop , buckets[i][0] = Double.MAX_VALUE; //Why are we storing Double.MAXVALUE in buckets[i][0] 
           buckets[i][0] = -1d;
           buckets[i][0] = Double.MAX_VALUE;    When I comment last two statements then also it produces same result.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA in fact that was a mistake. See my edit. That was meant to emphasise what each bucket does (delta, index, row value). I use `Double.MAX_VALUE` as a default for delta so the first delta will always be less than that, and as a default for "row value" so you can detect buckets which haven't had a match by testing for `bucket[2] == Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I can't understand what does bucket[2] == Double.MAX_VALUE do?What I found out on internet about Double.MAX_VALUE is that it will the highest possible values of double.I can't understand how it does store the current "closest" value in the third element.Please give me idea about it.

Comment: @SRY_JAVA Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68873/discussion-between-andy-brown-and-sry-java).

Comment: @AndyBrown  in order to use resultset.absolute(), I need to pass rowinex+1 as an argument to get required row .Y so??

Comment: @AndyBrown, I used this code .Can you please see the link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987668/issues-in-rs-absolute-when-same-coding-is-done-in-two-different-methods-with-d**

Comment: @AndyBrown have u seen that link??I'm stuck at rowindex.help me out,please.