# How to remove index 1 and 0 from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method in which I have array to hold values from sql query and did processing on the array to retrieve the required results.Now **I want to delete values or remove elements at index 0 and 1 from the array** .How to do so.As I'm getting exception that resultset has no current row, it occurs whenever index of array reached to 0 or 1.I want to remove elements from bucket array at index 0 and 1 in the last for loop of the following code-

```
    public  LinkedHashMap<Double, String> ClosestToMultiplesOfTen_User(String start,String end) throws SQLException {

        int row_id ;
        int bIdx = 0;

        //double[] vals = new double[47];
        double[] vals=null;

        int rowIndex = 0 ;
        int i=0;

        try
                { 
                  con = getConnection();
                  stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
               String sql="select distinct beam_current from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT where logtime between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"'"+
                          "and (beam_current like '%9.96' or beam_current like '%9.97' or beam_current like '%9.98' or  beam_current like '%9.99'  or beam_current like '%0' or beam_current like '%_0.01' or beam_current like '%_0.02' or beam_current like '%_0.03' or beam_current like '%_0.04' or beam_current like '%_0.05' or beam_current like '%_0.06') ";

                  System.out.println("Value of sql of FindClosestToMultiplesOfTen is"+sql);
                  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                  rs = stmt.getResultSet();

                 rs.last();
                    int row_cnt=rs.getRow();
                    System.out.println("row_count of closest " +row_cnt);
                     vals = new double[row_cnt];
                    rs.beforeFirst();
           while(rs.next()) 
            {
               for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
                 {
                   vals[i]  = rs.getDouble(1);
                   System.out.println("value of beam_current at closest is "+vals[i]);
                 }
                i++;
             }
            }
         catch( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println("\nException "+e);
            }
        //  get the max value, and its multiple of ten to get the number of buckets
        double max = java.lang.Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (double v : vals) max = Math.max(max, v);
        int bucketCount =1+(int)(max/10);
        double[] bucket =new double[bucketCount];

        System.out.println("bucketcount in closese"+bucketCount);

        //  initialise the buckets array to store the closest values
       double[][] buckets = new double[bucketCount][3];
     for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bucketCount; i1++){
            // store the current smallest delta in the first element
            buckets[i1][0] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
            // store the current "closest" index in the second element
            buckets[i1][1] = -1d;
            // store the current "closest" value in the third element
            buckets[i1][2] = java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        //  iterate the rows
        for (row_id=1 ; row_id < vals.length; row_id++)
        {
            //  get the value from the row
            double v = vals[row_id];
            //  get the closest multiple of ten to v
            double mult = getMultipleOfTen(v);
            //  get the absolute distance of v from the multiple of ten
            double delta = Math.abs(mult - v);
            //  get the bucket index based on the value of `mult`
           bIdx = (int)(mult / 10d);
          // System.out.println("value of bidx for bucket index is"+bIdx);
            //    test the last known "smallest delta" for this bucket
            if (buckets[bIdx][0] > delta)
            {

              buckets[bIdx][0] = delta;
              buckets[bIdx][1] = row_id;
              buckets[bIdx][2] = v;

            }
         }  

        for (int i1 =( buckets.length)-1;i1>0; i1--) 
       {
             bucket = buckets[i1];
             rowIndex = (int) bucket[1];
double rowValue = bucket[2];
             DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
             System.out.println("row index closeset "+rowIndex+ "value is  closest "+rowValue);

    user_current_map.put(java.lang.Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(rs.getDouble(1))),""); }
    System.out.println("user_current_map "+user_current_map);

    return user_current_map;
    }
```

Comment: You have to copy the elements you want from one array to another.  You could shrink the array (copying all the elements down one index) as well.  Much easier to use something like an `ArrayList`

Comment: @MadProgrammer,I don't want to use another array or arraylist. Can't I do changes in the same array.

Comment: Not really, arrays are non-mutable in the sense that once you create them you can't change their size.  You simply assign values to individual indices.  As I said, you could move all the elements down an index, but you'd need to make sure you `null` out any remaining elements at the end of the array...

Comment: Array sizes can't be changed once they're made. You can set the elements at 0 and 1 to be null, but you're still going to have an array with {null, null, element1, element2, ...}

Comment: Whoops, 30 seconds too late. Yeah, what @MadProgrammer said!

Comment: In the last for loop ,I want to remove all elements at index 0 and 1 from bucket array.Can you please show me how to do that??

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i1 =( buckets.length)-1;i1>0; i1--)
```

If you're having issues with elements with index 0 & 1 and you don't want them, instead of trying to remove them

you can simply avoid accessing them by small modification in for loop.

for (int i1 =( buckets.length)-1;i1>=2; i1--)

Or else if you really want  to remove, then you have to do something like the following.

```
     for (int i1 =0;i1<( buckets.length-2); i1++) 
      buckets[i] = buckets[i+2]; 
      buckets[buckets.length-1] = null;
      buckets[buckets.length-2] = null;
```

Comment: I changed my for loop,now the value is showing -1 as index.

Comment: value of rowindex is reaching -1 ,why it is so..???I do not want values after 2 .

Comment: Are you getting error in  the following line ?user_current_map.put(java.lang.Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(rs.getDouble(1))),"");

Comment: yes,in this line I use to get error that resultset has no current row.But now the page run ,with no exception but no result is shown and in console I'm getting values as **value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01**..I do not want 1 as index of bucket.

Comment: Actually the error is you're trying to access result set in that line, but the result set's cursor is after the last row. Since you've accessed the resultset using in the while(rs.next()) loop. After that you've not moved the cursor back. Either to rs.last() or r.beforeFirst() based on your need

Comment: That has to be done before the for loop
rs.last(); // or rs.before First();
**for (int i1 =( buckets.length)-1;i1>0; i1--) **
//inside for loop you may need to call rs.next(); (it may not applicable if you use rs.last();

Comment: Also worth knowing about `System.arraycopy` to save you having to write your own loop to do this.

Comment: @sathiyaseelan,I did ** rs.last();
   for (int i1 = (buckets.length)-1;i1>=2; i1--)**. But still I'm getting **value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308
value of bucket[1] is -1.01
row index 1value is 1.7976931348623157E308**

Comment: @tiddi rastogi .It would be better if you clarify what are you trying to do in the for loop? So that I can suggest what can be done. So far I can help with syntactical issues only. Thanks

Comment: @sathiyaseelan,Please see the link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203615/filter-map-to-one-row-per-multiple-of-ten-based-on-difference-in-decreasing-orde**, in the above mentioned link I have s[pecified the need of my code.The code was working fine when the for loop ws ** for (int i1 =1; i1 < buckets.length; i1++)**, now to reverse the result i.e firstly I was getting number as 10,20,30 nw to get 30,20,10 etc I changed my for loop to ** for (int i1 = (buckets.length)-1;i1>0; i1--) **,But now after changing I'm getting all those errors.

Comment: @sathiyaseelan,did u get wat i wanted??

Answer (score 0):

you can't do changes in array, but you can declare a new array or you can use an arraylist like this:

```
arrayList<String> arrayListNamet = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayListName.remove(0);
arrayListName.remove("element");
```