# How to skip array index when index has values 1 or 0 in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a method through which I stores value in an array.Now **I want to skip those index whenever I get index number as 0 or 1 in java or to delete values at index 0 and 1**.Is there any mechanism to do so?

Comment: Please provide some code and describe in more detail. It is unclear how your array looks like etc.

Comment: Can you show your code so we can understand what you mean by "skip"?

Comment: `if (index > 1) ...` ?

Comment: PLEASE REFER THE LINK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203615/filter-map-to-one-row-per-multiple-of-ten-based-on-difference-in-decreasing-orde AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941610/filter-array-to-one-row-per-multiple-of-ten-based-on-difference.Whole question will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

The following example should clear things out

```
Z :for(int i =0;i<num;i++)
   {
     if ((i==0) ||(i==1))
        continue Z;
      //code for storing element in array
   }
```